# Primary Category display in EE2.6 Relationships loop

Tags: relationships, categories

I can find no way of displaying any of the Primary Category tags within the new EE2.6 Relationships field loop.

It works fine with Playa fields.

Does anyone know if there is a way to display Primary Category tags within EE2.6 Relationship Child loops?

Comment: Just to confirm, you're using _Solspace_ Primary Category? Can you update your question with a bit of the template code you've tried that does not work?

Comment: Actually, I switched to using the Plugin version instead of the Tag Pair and everything works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the PriCat Tag Pair inside a EE2.6 Relationships Tag Pair, the following works perfectly:

```
{exp:primary_category entry_id='{my_related_field:entry_id}'}{primary_category_parent_url_title}{/exp:primary_category}
```